# What to use instead of aws.Endpoint in AWS SDK v3?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I have started migration of AWS SDK from v2 to v3. Can`t figure out what to use to create endpoint for S3.

In v2 I have:
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ep = new aws.Endpoint(`s3.region.amazonaws.com`);
What package need to use in V3 for this ?

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?

const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const s3 = new S3Client({
region: 'region'
});

for custom endpoint, try this:

const s3 = new S3Client({
endpoint: 'https://s3.region.yourendpoint',
region: 'region'
});

Comment: Hello. Yes use endpoint option. In our code we use STS service to get credentials and full Endpoint object, that is why I was trying to find how to create full Endpoint object, but I didn`t find it. In finale result I skipped the endpoint and pass only credentials and all work.